# Xcode Javascript JSON parsing

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, json, parsing

I am currently creating a native web app that intercepts JavaScript events from a UIWebView and translates the data back and forth via modified url strings similar to the method described here (http://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2012/09/calling-objective-c-methods-from-javascript-in-a-uiwebview/). At one of the intercept points, I am getting back an array of JSON objects that I need to parse, and I'm at a loss after several hours of searching on how to do this.

Is parsing the JSON object to a string something I need to do in my injected javascript file, or is there some way I can pass the object back (using this implementation) to my objective-c classes and handle the parsing there? If it needs to be done in the javascript file, how would I accomplish that? Since this isn't truly a web browser, I can't simply call JSON.parse() because the necessary libraries aren't there.

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++)
{
    var jsonString = jsonData[i];
    alert('jsonData :' + jsonString);
}

execute('communicateWithApp://event=' + jsonData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.json.org/js.html if you want convert JSON object to string.

---

You can parse JSON using javascript directly, no extra lib needed.

`var myJSONObject = eval('(' + myJSONtext + ')');`

You can also parse a JSON string in Objective-C using NSJSONSerialization. You may cover string to NSData first using NSString's method dataUsingEncoding: or something else.

Comment: My understanding was that eval converted a JSON string into a JSON object, I need to go the other way, from JSON object into JSON string. Is that incorrect?

Comment: Sorry, I got it wrong. If you want covert object to json string, why not try some third part lib? eg. http://www.json.org/js.html